# How to transfer data via an Apple Lightning port

Tags: iphone, usb-host

I have a board on which a microcontroller reads the output from a sensor. I am thinking of connecting it to an iPhone so that the iPhone can read data from it. The board should also be powered by iPhone/iPad. If it were in Android, I would look for the docs related to USB On-The-Go. But I am not sure what I should do with iOS devices. Can anyone give some hints? Thanks!

Update: I just find one needs to participate Apple's MFi program to develop accessories for Apple devices. So it may or may not be something for hobbyists. But apart from that, I am still eager to know the technical solution to my question.

Comment: the solution is use an android phone, or pay apple many $$$ and become an official apple partner. you can always make your micro the usb host, hope that the iwhatever can act like a mass storage (unlikely) and write to a file via the micro, while the app on the phone would read that same file. that would be a mess, but that might work.

Comment: What kind of data rate?  Can you use BLE?  Or an audio modem?

Comment: @ChrisStratton Data rate is low, can be less than 20 or even 10 bytes per second. BLE is another possibility. But the idea is the board is to be powered by the smartphone so that no onboard battery is needed. BLE doesn't consume lots of energy, but the sensor can drain a coin cell battery much faster than BLE.

Comment: @shva - *must* it be an iPhone? I agree with Vladimir Cravero, use Android. Also there are many more android phones about. For  the last couple of years, they are spec'd to support USB-on-the-go, and so should be able to supply some current. Otherwise, pay up for Apple's MFi program. I did spot someone offering to make a kit to interface an iPhone to electronics about a year ago, but I haven't seen if that got off the ground, and I wouldn't be too surprised if it didn't. But a search engine might help.